# Sprites; changing frames is not fluid in C++ Allegro 5

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

Watch the video: https://youtu.be/i2EXKY3EQPo
The dragon movement is not fluid. It's like if all the frames were changing at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

```
shipImage = al_load_bitmap("dragon_stationary.png");
ship.maxFrame = 5;
ship.curFrame = 0;
ship.frameCount = 0;
ship.frameDelay = 50;
ship.frameWidth = 180;
ship.frameHeight = 126;
ship.animationColumns = 5;
ship.animationDirection = 1;
//this occurs every 1/60 of a second
void drawShip(SpaceShip &ship, ALLEGRO_BITMAP *flyingShip) {
    if (++ship.frameCount >= ship.frameDelay) {
        if (++ship.curFrame >= ship.maxFrame) {
            ship.curFrame = 0;
            ship.frameCount = 0;
        }
    }

    al_draw_bitmap_region(ship.image, ship.curFrame * ship.frameWidth, 0, ship.frameWidth, ship.frameHeight, ship.x, ship.y, 0);
```

This is the sprite:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plotting out what happens for various values:

| frameCount | curFrame |

| ---------- | -------- |

| 0          | 0        |

| 1          | 0        |

| 2          | 0        |

| ...        | ...      |

| 49         | 0        |

| 50         | 1        |

| 51         | 2        |

| 52         | 3        |

| 54         | 4        |

| 55         | 5        |

| 56         | 0        |

| 0          | 0        |

Note that when `frameCount` hits 50, it blasts through all your frames in sequence, then only resets once the animation is complete. You need to reset `frameCount` every timme it reaches `frameDelay`

Comment: Sorry about the format, apparently stackoverflow [doesn't support tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: Thanks! Another thing, can you please tell me how to pass an array of bitmaps to a function? 
ALLEGRO_BITMAP * shipImage[maxFrameShip];
initShip(ship, shipImage[maxFrameShip]); 
void initShip(SpaceShip &ship, ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image) {
ship.image[0] = image[0];
}
this is the way I have it now and it does not work "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" 
What's the correct way?

Comment: Search for that error, then open a new question if you can't find an answer